# Why is Task.Delay(1) necessary to advance clock when unit testing with .NET TimeProvider?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-8.0, polly, retry-logic

I have configured a retry based pipeline with Polly.

```
// Using Polly for retry logic
private readonly ResiliencePipeline _retryPipeline = new ResiliencePipelineBuilder { TimeProvider = timeProvider }
    .AddRetry(new RetryStrategyOptions
    {
        ShouldHandle = new PredicateBuilder().Handle<ConditionalCheckFailedException>(),
        Delay = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(_backoffFactor),
        MaxRetryAttempts = _maxAttempts - 1,

        // Linear backoff increases the delay each time by the backoff factor
        BackoffType = DelayBackoffType.Linear,
        OnRetry = onRetryArguments =>
        {
            logger.LogWarning(
                "Failed to acquire lock. Retrying. {@LogContext}",
                new { onRetryArguments });
            return ValueTask.CompletedTask;
        }
    })
    .Build();
```

Which I execute using

```
// Attempt to store the lock with backoff retry 
LockResult result = await _retryPipeline.ExecuteAsync(
   async _ => await AttemptLockStorageAsync(lockId, expiryMilliseconds, attempts++),
   cancellationTokenSource.Token);
```

When unit testing, I find that I have to add a `Task.Delay(1)` in order for Polly to perform the retries

```
// Act
Func<Task<DistributedLock>> func = async () =>
{
    Task<DistributedLock> result = _distributedLockService.AcquireLockAsync(lockId);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        _timeProvider.Advance(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000 * i + 1));
        await Task.Delay(1);
    }

    return await result;
};

// Assert
// We expect that we should be able to attempt 5 full times, rather than getting a TaskCancelledException.
(await func.Should().ThrowAsync<TimeoutException>()).WithMessage(
    $"Could not acquire lock {lockId}. Attempted 5 times.");
```

Why is the `Task.Delay` necessary?

**Edit**

TimeProvider provided to the SUT via the primary constructor.

```cs
public class DistributedLockService(
    IDistributedLockRepository distributedLockRepository,
    ILogger<DistributedLockService> logger,
    TimeProvider timeProvider)
    : IDisposable, IDistributedLockService
```

FakeTimer is provided in the unit test constructor

```cs
    private readonly FakeTimeProvider _timeProvider = new();

    public DistributedLockServiceTests()
    {
        _timeProvider.SetUtcNow(DateTimeOffset.Parse("2024-01-23", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        _distributedLockService = new DistributedLockService(
            _distributedLockRepository.Object,
            _logger.Object,
            _timeProvider);
    }
```

Filed a bug report based on minimal reproduction
https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/issues/1932

Comment: Advance is synchronous so if Polly's timer callback notifies something that the timer has elapsed asynchronously then that may not be scheduled until the task running your test hits an await.

Comment: Are you using [`FakeTimeProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.time.testing.faketimeprovider?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0) in your unit test?

Comment: Could you please share with us how do you inject the TimeProvider into your SUT?

Comment: @PeterCsala - See edit with TimeProvider (FakeTimer) setup

Answer (score 0):

First let me show you the working code

```
//Arrange
var delays = new List<TimeSpan>();
var timeProvider = new FakeTimeProvider();
var sut = new ResiliencePipelineBuilder { TimeProvider = timeProvider }
.AddRetry(new RetryStrategyOptions
{
    ShouldHandle = _ => new ValueTask<bool>(true),
    Delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
    MaxRetryAttempts = 3,
    BackoffType = DelayBackoffType.Linear,
    OnRetry = args =>
    {
        delays.Add(args.RetryDelay);
        return default;
    }
})
.Build();

//Act
var executing = sut.ExecuteAsync(_ => new ValueTask<int>(0)).AsTask();
while (!executing.IsCompleted)
{
    timeProvider.Advance(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
}

await executing;

//Assert
Assert.Collection(
    delays, 
    item => Assert.Equal(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), item),
    item => Assert.Equal(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4), item),
    item => Assert.Equal(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6), item)
);
```

The trick here is the following: call the `Advance` in a `while` loop not in a `for` loop.

To test failure scenario the `Act` part needs to be adjusted like this

```
Task executing = sut.ExecuteAsync(_ => throw new Exception()).AsTask();
while (!executing.IsFaulted)
{
    timeProvider.Advance(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
}

await Assert.ThrowsAsync<Exception>(() => executing);
```

Comment: While I appreciate the answer, you are changing the nature of the test quite a bit.  I need to utilize a  `Func<Task<DistributedLock>>` not just a `Task`.  Polling an async task for it's completion status isn't the most efficient thing to do.  I also want to advance the timer a specific number of times in specific increments.  It's not so much about making it work, as it is understanding why the Delay is necessary in my shown code.

Comment: @RichardCollette Okay, then please try to turn your code into a minimal reproducible example to be able to run it locally, debug it, adjust it as needed, etc.

Comment: See minimal repro - https://github.com/rcollette/PollyRetryFakeTimeProviderIssue

Comment: @RichardCollette I've posted my observations on the github issue: https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/issues/1932#issuecomment-1914306152. Long story short: I think this bug is not Polly related.